# query pattern is missing Error

Tags: firebase, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

i have created one intent as "Test Intent", i have created one firebase functions. In the action simulator i have tried "Talk to my test App" , it called the firebase function and returned content in Welcome Intent "Welcome to my dialogFlow agent!" .

Then i have typed "Test", i am getting content from default fallback Intent "Sorry, I didn't get that." . 
  If i try to integration, i am getting error as "Request contains an invalid argument.
Query pattern is missing for custom intent 'Test Intent'"
 how to fix the error ?
 how to make it to call Test intent?
content in index.js is

```
 /* See https: github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs
  for Dialogflow fulfillment library docs, samples, and to report issues*/
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {Card, Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');

process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug';   //enables lib debugging statements

exports.dialogflowSample = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
 const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
 console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
 console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));

 function welcome(agent) {
   agent.add(`Welcome to my dialogFlow agent!`);
 }

 function fallback(agent) {
   agent.add(`I didn't understand`);
   agent.add(`I'm sorry, can you try again?`);
}

 /*    Uncomment and edit to make your own intent handler
     uncomment `intentMap.set('your intent name here', yourFunctionHandler);`
     below to get this function to be run when a Dialogflow intent is matched*/
  function yourFunctionHandler(agent) {
    agent.add(`This message is from Dialogflow's Cloud Functions for Firebase editor!`);
    agent.add(new Card({
        title: `Title: this is a card title`,
       // imageUrl: 'https: developers.google.com/actions/images/badges/XPM_BADGING_GoogleAssistant_VER.png',
        text: `This is the body text of a card.  You can even use line\n  breaks and emoji! `,
         buttonText: 'This is a button',
         buttonUrl: 'https: assistant.google.com/'
       })
     );
     agent.add(new Suggestion(`Quick Reply`));
     agent.add(new Suggestion(`Suggestion`));
     agent.setContext({ name: 'weather', lifespan: 2, parameters: { city: 'Rome' }});
   }

 /*    Uncomment and edit to make your own Google Assistant intent handler
     uncomment `intentMap.set('your intent name here', googleAssistantHandler);`
     below to get this function to be run when a Dialogflow intent is matched*/
   function googleAssistantHandler(agent) {
     let conv = agent.conv();  // Get Actions on Google library conv instance
     conv.ask('Hello from the Actions on Google client library!')  // Use Actions on Google library
     agent.add(conv);   //Add Actions on Google library responses to your agent's response
   }
  /*   See https: github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs/tree/master/samples/actions-on-google
     for a complete Dialogflow fulfillment library Actions on Google client library v2 integration sample

   Run the proper function handler based on the matched Dialogflow intent name*/
 let intentMap = new Map();
 intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', welcome);
 //intentMap.set('Default Fallback Intent', fallback);
 intentMap.set('Test Intent', fallback);
 intentMap.set('your intent name here', googleAssistantHandler);
 agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

Comment: Is this the older V1 library code? I don't see WebhookClient used in newer example code - e.g. https://github.com/actions-on-google/dialogflow-number-genie-nodejs/blob/master/functions/index.js. Just wondering if there was a library version number issue. Otherwise I was wondering if it was an error in your dialogflow definition of the intent - e.g. something to do with parameter bindings for "Test Intent" in the dialogflow console, rather than the NodeJS code. (I was trying to think what "query pattern" might mean - I was thinking of parsing the training phrases)

Comment: https://github.com/actions-on-google/dialogflow-number-genie-nodejs/blob/master/functions/index.js   is it new version code? I am using versions  "actions-on-google": "^2.0.1",
    "firebase-admin": "~5.12.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^1.0.1",
    "dialogflow": "^0.1.0",
    "dialogflow-fulfillment": "0.3.0-beta.2"

Comment: That is new code - see how number genie no longer calls "new WebhookClient". I suspect WebhookClient is V1 code.